# Displays won't unsleep

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, display, gnome-shell

Ubuntu 22.10, dual monitors (if that matters). Nvidia P620 card + Nvidia proprietary drivers 525. System set to not suspend, but to blank screen after a period.

Most of the time, displays won't power on after blanking. They just act like they aren't connected. Sometimes re-plugging the DP cable fixes it. Sometimes power off/on the monitor fixes it. Sometimes I need to reboot.

I'd be happy with disabling the actual monitor sleep and just let them blank if that's possible.

Comment: X11 or wayland?

Comment: I was on X11 for whatever reason. I just switched to Wayland. Will report back if it makes a difference.

Comment: No that definitely did not help. If anything the problem is worse.

Comment: Sometimes in X11 you can play with `xset dpms force off ; xset dpms force on` possibly with delays to fix this.  I answered a question previously with that solution but can't find it just now.